# how to convert string to array to new another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have static something like code below.

```
let str='4'
let tmp=['A', 'B']
```

I want it to be like that

```
let myCode=4:['A', 'B']
```

Comment: What you want is not valid JavaScript. Do you want it to be `{ 4:['A', 'B'] }`, i.e. an object? If this is the case: `let myCode = { [str]: tmp }`

Comment: It works fine, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is invalid JavaScript. If you want this result:

```
myCode = {
    4: ['A', 'B']
};
```

Then just do this:

```
let myCode = { [str]: tmp };
```

Or:

```
let myCode = {};
myCode[str] = tmp;
```

Comment: `str` should be `[str]`. The latter syntax is called "Computed property name".

Comment: OK, I'll try that and see what happens. Go ahead and edit with correct syntax. It does seems to work after I've tested it however @undefined

Comment: Both syntaxes are valid but do different things. The `str` creates `'str'` key and `[str]` creates a key by using `str` variable's value.

Comment: It works fine, Thank you​ for your refly